# Using Javascript to get content from another website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that puts all the content in a database, so I cannot put PHP code into the plugin, it won't execute. It does allow Javascript though.

So how would I go about using javascript to contact a page and get the data, if I have the data just pass the content, like this:

```
field1=data|field2=data|field3=data|field4=data
```

like that string.

Is there a way to get that content using javascript or jquery, so that I could parse that and pull the data I need?

I can build a php script to output that data, since I cannot have PHP executed in the plugin, so I could still securely get the data I need, since I could pull the data and make sure to pass a key, so it is secure.

Comment: Yes, [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: awesome. have not thought of that. my bad. My brain is messed up still from my sever sleep apnea... Thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck learning.

Comment: I put some of the code on my website from the example just to see what would happen, and it returns: "There was a problem with the request."
Should I have the page print headers before the data? I have it just "echo" the data I want it to have, but no headers, so maybe it is thinking the page did not load correct?
What do you think?

Comment: @Rich: You don't only need headers, you specifically need CORS headers to be one of the headers you send. Google CORS or Access-Control-Allow-Origin